# How to fix SimpleImputer: "ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

I have a dataset **tele2_sub** as follows:

```
    MonthlyCharges  TotalCharges
0   29.85           109.90
1   56.95           NaN
2   NaN             108.15
3   42.30           1840.75
4   70.70           NaN
5   NaN             820.50
6   89.10           1949.40
7   NaN             NaN
8   104.80          3046.05
9   54.10           354.95
```

I use `SimpleImputer` to complete missing values:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values='NaN',strategy='median',verbose=0)
imp.fit(tele2_sub)
```

However, I receive an error.

```
Error: ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The `SimpleImputer` initialization call should set `missing_values` to `numpy.nan` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='median', verbose=0)
imp.fit(tele2_sub)
```